# Python - Changing image color when pasting in a new image

Tags: python, image

I am creating a square white canvas/image for a picture. I then paste my image in the center of the new canvas and everything works great. However, the color of the image changes. I can't figure out which variable to change to fix this issue.

This is my code:

```
img = Image.open(llt)
img_w, img_h = img.size
newImage = Image.new("RGB", (max(img_w, img_h),max(img_w, img_h)),"white")
bg_w, bg_h = newImage.size
offset = (round((bg_w - img_w) / 2), round((bg_h - img_h) / 2))
newImage.paste(img, offset)
newImage.show()
```

Comment: What kind of change do you mean. Does it increase the intensity of a specific color or something?
I ran your code and it worked but could not see the difference.
Just converted to int the round part like this:
offset = (int(round((bg_w - img_w) / 2)), int(round((bg_h - img_h) / 2)))
because of some error.

Comment: I am taking pictures of a grey product and it becomes bluish when I run the code. I will post the image on Monday when I get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image like this:

```
llt = "the_image.ext"
img = Image.open(llt)
img_w, img_h = img.size
newImage = Image.new("RGB", (max(img_w, img_h),max(img_w, img_h)),"white")
bg_w, bg_h = newImage.size
offset = (int(round((bg_w - img_w) / 2)), int(round((bg_h - img_h) / 2)))
newImage.paste(img, offset)
newImage.save("modified.jpg");
#newImage.show()
```